# Is it possible to change Request IP/Request Context in Action Filter or Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

My scenario is that our already developed website (which relies a lot on User IP Address `Request.UserHostAddress`) is now deployed behind CloudFlare proxy. Therefore, now we need to check if there is CloudFlare's original IP header.

I am intending to write a Filter/Module that can run before Action takes place so we do not have to modify the code. I need the Filter/Module to replace the `UserHostAddress` with the value from the Header if it exist.

However, I do not know if Action Filter can actually modify the Requeset UserHostAddress, nor could I find anything to override the creation of the RequestContext object.

Is it possible to achieve this through Action Filter and/or IIS Module? If there is, what keyword should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UserHostAddress property in the HttpRequest  class is read only, so it can't be changed, but you can add an extension method in the HttpRequest  class and make it read by default from the UserHostAddress  and if a specific header or route data is present, ex: OriginalUserHostAddress, then return its value.

Inside the action filter, you can check the firewall headers and if it exist, then set a route data variable or temp data variable and read it from the extension method.